# Valuation of rare domain names

Tags: domains

There are plenty of resources for domain name transactions, but I haven't been able to find any information for "rare" domain names, like cat.com or dog.com. Is there someplace that lists transaction prices for rare domain names? Do people sell these on eBay, or is there a specialized auction site? How do people in the business generate valuations for these?